Install on Raspberry Pi 5 to partitioned NVMe drive?
I'm installing 24.04 to a NVMe drive (I have the Pimoroni base and a 2TB m.2)
Ultimately, I'd like to install it with a /home partition so that when 24.10 drops in a couple of months, I can perform a fresh installation, leaving all the data in my /home partition undisturbed
Is there a way to install Ubuntu on the NVMe this way? The only way that I can seem to install is to use the entire drive. This way I'll have to move all the data out of /home to an external device, install, then move it all back.
Is there a way to accomplish this?
Thank you

You mention release; but not which 24.04 product... eg. are you asking about Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop? Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Server? or a flavor or 24.04?

This question is similar to: How to use manual partitioning during installation?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
